# Thread was being aborted error during de-serialization (but it wasn't aborted)

Tags: c#, multithreading, xmlserializer, threadabortexception

Very strange error, basically I fire off a thread once a user has logged into my app which loads data from an xml file using this code snippet:

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(String Path)
    {
        T Result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(Path))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    if (fs.Length > 0)
                    {
                        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer s = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                        Result = (T)s.Deserialize(fs);
                    }
                    fs.Close();
                }

                // force clean up!
                GC.Collect();
            }

            return Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Deserialize '{0}' : {1}", Path, ex.ToString());
            return Result;
        }
    }
```

The XML file that it is loading is about 3MB, if that matters.  EVERY single time it fails on one particular file with this exception:

> Deserialize 'C:\bin\Debug\Settings\Objects.xml' :
>   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object
>   obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)
>        at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.InvokeReader(XmlMapping mapping, XmlReader xmlReader, XmlDeserializationEvents events, String
>   encodingStyle)
>        at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>        at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream)
>
> at Classes.XmlSerializer.Deserialize[T](String Path) in
>   c:\Classes\XmlSerializer.cs:line 82   Unable to load previous data!
>   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>
> at Classes.XmlSerializer.Deserialize[T](String Path) in
>   c:\Classes\XmlSerializer.cs:line 96
>        at Controllers.ObjectDataCollection.ObjectThread.LoadData() in c:\Controllers\ObjectDataCollection.cs:line 74

I am at a complete loss as to how to debug this further.  I know for a fact the thread isn't being aborted because the next line after the attempted deserialization is a loop which scans for things, and it runs perfectly fine (the thread isn't restarted, it's only started it one place).

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can debug this further? I'm at a complete loss here. Here is all the code: http://pastebin.com/F30vD9KL

Comment: Do you have an XSD for your XML that you could validate your XML against?

Comment: No I don't but it's valid XML

Comment: What's strange is it only seems to happen when the file gets large, like over 3MB or so

Comment: Hmm.. 3MB of XML.  Hmm, give it a bigger stack and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the auto generated .cs serialization code to see if you can get more details as described here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HOWTODebugIntoANETXmlSerializerGeneratedAssembly.aspx

Comment: Also be sure to break on all exceptions using Crtl-Alt-E - it should break on the line of code in the auto generated .cs file causing the problem.

Comment: How do I give it a bigger stack?

Comment: Interestingly enough I followed that blog, the .dll file is there, but no .cs file :(

Comment: Hmmm let me think on this more - I have been able to debug the generated serialization assemblies before in the past….I didn’t have to explicitly find the file though – VS opened it when an exception was thrown in it (using CTRL-ALT-E)

Comment: @Geesu were you able to solve this issue? I've run across the same problem 7 years after you asked it.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure, but this is the final class I ended up using years ago: https://gist.github.com/Geesu/51cc93d5c712d3827e09f972849b07cd